# ConnectWise <-> TFS synchronization

Tags: azure-devops, synchronization, tfs-workitem, ticket-system

we are going to use TFS (Azure Devops) and ConnectWise Manage at the same time.
In short, we need to provide synchronization between those two systems when working with a working item / a ticket correspondingly, i.e. we can insert the reference to TFS working item into ConnectWise ticket - then corresponding TFS working item will be updated with ConnectWise ticket reference and vice versa. Also, some fields are to be re-used in both systems and updated.
I've started to look for the information, but seems cannot find anything basic - where to start from and how to implement this (how it will look like - some intermediate listener listening for both servers and updating items here and there or... ? What language to be used - is it some of .NET language using some specific framework? Or just some PowerShell scripts? What authentication is to be used? What settings do I need to ask our organisation to make in their Azure Devops / ConnectWise account? etc.)
Could you please point me in right direction?

Comment: Check out TaskTop. There is no built-in easy way to do this, especially in a robust manner with just a couple of scripts or functions.

Comment: @jessehouwing TaskTop replied they did not support ConnectWise... :(

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to integrate Azure devops with ConnectWise Manage. You can try connect your Azure DevOps and ConnectWise Manage via [Zapier](https://zapier.com/apps/azure-devops/integrations/connectwise-manage).  It's easy to connect Azure DevOps + ConnectWise Manage and requires absolutely zero coding experience.

You can synchronize between the two services by selecting a trigger and then selecting an action.

[image]

Comment: I've read about Zapier before - but I thought we might want to use a 'free-of-charge' approach without any limitations... I am ready to get my hands in it, in case I know where to start ;-) But if you say it's too complex and long - well, maybe this means something like Zapier needs to be used...

Comment: Currently, I haven't found other integration methods yet. Once I find another method, I will update it in answer.